# NetworkOnMainThreadException при попытке использовать AsyncTask

Tags: android, jsoup, android-asynctask

Первые попытки применить `AsyncTask`. Вроде всё должно работать, но почему-то — нет.

Я решил создать внутренний класс `extends AsyncTask` в нужном мне классе, а из него уже вызвать нужный мне класс с методом, использующим соединение.

Но что-то пошло не ок.

```
public class Converter {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Strategy strategy;
    private Map<String, Currency> currencies;

    public Converter(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
        strategy = new Strategy();
    }

    public void process() {
    }

    public void prepareDB() {
//        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        currencies = new DBConnection().doInBackground();
    }

    private class DBConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Map<String, Currency>> {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, Currency> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return new Strategy().getCurrencies();
        }
    }
}
```

> Класс Strategy:

```
public class Strategy {
    private Map<String, Currency> currencies = new HashMap<>();
    private final String URL_FORMAT = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=%s";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
    private static final String REFERRER = "none";

    protected Document getDocument() throws Exception {
        return Jsoup.connect(String.format(URL_FORMAT, getDate())).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
    }

    public static String getDate() {
        return "11/11/2011";
//        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
    }

    public Map<String, Currency> getCurrencies() {
        Map<String, Currency> map = new HashMap<>();
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = getDocument();
            Log.d("process", "document created");
            String e = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "data").get(0).getElementsByTag("td").text();
//            System.out.println(e);
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(e, " ");
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String validToken = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                if (validToken.length() == 3 && areDigits(validToken)) {
                    Currency currency = new Currency();
                    currency.setdCode(validToken);
                    currency.setCode(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken()));
                    String s = null;
                    while (true) {
                        if ((s = stringTokenizer.nextToken()).matches("^[0-9,]+$")) break;
                    }
                    currency.setRate(Double.parseDouble(s.replace(",", ".")));
                    currency.setDate(getDate());
                    map.put(currency.getdCode(), currency);
                    Log.d("adding to array", currency.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("exception", "catched");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    private boolean areDigits(String validToken) {
        char[] ch = validToken.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ch) if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Метод, который выбрасывает NetworkOnMainThreadException:

```
protected Document getDocument() throws Exception {
    return Jsoup.connect(String.format(URL_FORMAT, getDate())).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
}
```

> StackTrace:

```
04-23 08:07:34.443 30209-30209/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10062: Read-only file system
04-23 08:07:34.443 30209-30209/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
04-23 08:07:34.443 30209-30209/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-23 08:07:34.532 30209-30209/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter
04-23 08:07:34.866 30209-30209/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? D/exception: catched
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-23 08:07:35.061 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:651)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Strategy.getDocument(Strategy.java:22)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Strategy.getCurrencies(Strategy.java:34)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Converter$DBConnection.doInBackground(Converter.java:38)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Converter.prepareDB(Converter.java:30)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-23 08:07:35.062 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-23 08:07:35.063 30209-30209/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-23 08:07:35.072 30209-30244/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                   [ 04-23 08:07:35.075 30209:30209 D/         ]
                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb434c370, tid 30209
04-23 08:07:35.085 30209-30209/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
04-23 08:07:35.132 30209-30244/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 08:07:35.132 30209-30244/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-23 08:07:35.139 30209-30244/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

Интересно не только понять, что я делаю не так, но и увидеть реализацию, чтобы в последующем отталкиваться от неё и не отвлекать уважаемых Знатоков.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы запустить асинхронную задачу через `AsyncTask` необходимо вызывать метод `execute()`. Метод `doInBackground()` вызовется сам после запуска задачи.

```
new DBConnection().execute();
```

После вызова `execute()` сработают три ключевых метода жизненного цикла `AsyncTask`: `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()`, `onPostExecute()`.

Переопределите метод `onPostExecute()`, чтобы там получить результат и присвоить его ссылке `currencies`.

Стоит отметить, что первый и третий методы выполняются в UI-потоке.

Comment: удалил свой ответ, так как вы раньше добавили, за замечание спасибо ) не углядел

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо!